# Node.js not finding the default system root

Tags: node.js, react-native, powershell, npm, sanity

I was trying to configure sanityCMS on my machine and node.js decided to "forget" the system root. I spent a couple hours trying to fix it and since it decided not to, I went back to my expo project which now does not want to run the web compiler. The default environment variable goes to 'undefined' instead of being  "C:/Windows". Here is the complete error log

```
Error: spawn undefined\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn undefined\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  path: 'undefined\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'giganticAssStringWhichMightBeSensitive'
  ]
}
```

I'm running node 18.14.2 on Windows 10 which upto this point did not have any issues.

I tried everything from reinstalling node and nvm and ended up ditching nvm. The system PATH variables are all set correctly, and I tried almost every single fix I could find.

Comment: Did you try environment variable "SystemRoot"?

Comment: Yep... It kept throwing the same error. I decided to just copy over the files to my WSL Instance and work on it from there.

Comment: you may just be logging into a System Account with not environment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding this env variable to the npm run script

```
--env SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows
```

e.g.

```
"start:windows": "webpack-dev-server --env build=dev --env SYSTEMROOT=C:\\Windows",
```

Hope it helps.